# Install ubuntu 16.10 into Oracle VirtualBox v5.1

Tags: virtualbox, 16.10, oracle

I downloaded the latest version of Oracle VirtualBox for Windows and installed it (version 5.1.20). Then I downloaded `Ubuntu 16.10 ("Yakkety")` from the [Oracle Linux distributions page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Note that the extension of the downloaded file is `deb`.

When I started the VM for the first I was prompted for a ISO file, couldn't find the option I needed (basically got confused as it was asking for an `iso` but I only had a `deb` file!). Tried to continue but got the expected message: `FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.`

How do I install the `virtualbox-5.1_5.1.20-114628-Ubuntu-yakkety_i386.deb` into my VM?

Comment: Those .deb packages are for installing VirtualBox on Linux _hosts_, not for installing Linux guests. You need to download a Ubuntu 16.10 ISO instead, just like what VirtualBox asked for.

Comment: Oh! Ok will continue looking for the uBuntu ISO I guess. Actually, it was all in the title wasn't it...`Download VirtualBox for Linux Hosts`. Oops. Thanks!

Comment: Pick an appropriate one here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/yakkety/

Answer (score 0):

1. Drink some coffee
2. Download the correct iso file from here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download
3. Proceed installing Ubuntu